# 500 server error on submitting a user create form

Tags: laravel

get request to user is showing error below on the console.Error occur when submitting create user form

The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:8000/api/user

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});

Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);
Route::get('profile', 'API\UserController@profile');
Route::get('findUser', 'API\UserController@search');
Route::put('profile', 'API\UserController@updateProfile');
```

> [2018-12-20 16:09:08] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'photo' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `type`, `bio`, `photo`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (B L Praveen, blpraveen@gmail.com, admin, Web Developer, , $2y$10$fDrNkYfMSIl9TcpwlLsSROCLhpmXvrSIunBbbgLH6KTikY0YeZjMi, 2018-12-20 16:09:08, 2018-12-20 16:09:08)) {"userId":1,"email":"blpraveen2004@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'photo' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `type`, `bio`, `photo`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (B L Praveen, blpraveen@gmail.com, admin, Web Developer, , $2y$10$fDrNkYfMSIl9TcpwlLsSROCLhpmXvrSIunBbbgLH6KTikY0YeZjMi, 2018-12-20 16:09:08, 2018-12-20 16:09:08)) at F:\xamp\htdocs\laravStart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'photo' cannot be null at F:\xamp\htdocs\laravStart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458)

Comment: 500 errors can be caused by almost anything that makes the server unhappy.  You need to do some more troubleshooting.

Comment: can you show stacktrace?

Comment: Are you sure that your UserController is bug-free?

Comment: error is shown in the console

Comment: Check your server logs. The `laravel.log` file.

Comment: But we can't see the console.

Comment: How to test Post request

Comment: either you should make the column in the DB for the image to be default null or you should set a default value for every time you are inserting data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `UserController` in POST handler (probably `store` method which create user in DB) - when you save user to DB  the column `photo` is empty - but DB not accept empty value of that column. Correct you code which save user to DB or correct your DB to accept empty value of `photo` column in `users` table.